# Xamarin Forms Staging, Production and Development environment

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I setup different environments in a Xamarin Forms application? (production, staging, development)

Currently, I'm using the `#if DEBUG` in my code in order to distinguish parts of the code that I'm using during development. So is there a better way to distinguish between different environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add new configurations in Configuration manager for your three environments.

[image]

Then you can add new compilation symbols in the project properties to support your conditional compilation statements

[image]

Then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you wouldn't want mixing up the development version of your app with the production one. Fortunately, you can target different environments through multiple project configurations.

For example, you could have *DEV*, *TEST* & *PROD* configurations.
To do this, open your ***.csproj** file and add following snippet:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
...
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configurations>DEV;TEST;PROD</Configurations>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And from there, you can customize the project configuration in your ***.csproj** file for each of the targeted environments, accordingly to your needs:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
...
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DEV' ">
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'TEST' ">
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'PROD' ">
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This can be relatively long and complex, so if you want to see it in action, I have published a whole article [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tips/multi-environments-project-configuration/) on this to guide you through it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: I know this can be controversial, but I found this from Jon Skeet: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20532